# The supremum of numbers $c$ such that $f\ge c$ a.e. is finite

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

We have a measurable function $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$. We assume that $f$ is non constant a.e. This means that $f(x) \ne c$  a.e. and also implies that $\mu^*(\{x \in X : f(x) = c\}) = 0$. Also we assume dat $f(x) \geq 0$  for all $x \in X$.

Now I need to find $c_0$, the supremum of the set B = $\{ c \in \mathbb{R}: \mu^*(\{x \in X : f(x) \leq c\}) = 0 \}$. But it is not very clear to me why this supremum exists. I know that $B$ is a non-empty set, because $c=0$ is always in it, because:

$\mu^*(\{x \in X : f(x) \leq 0\}) = \mu^*(\{x \in X : f(x) = 0\}) = 0$ (because $f$ non constant a.e.)

But why is this set $B$ bounded? I need to prove this, because the supremum of B only exists when B is nonempty and bounded from above.

Comment: $$X = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \{ x : f(x) \leqslant n\}$$

Comment: I'm very sorry, but how does this help me to show that B is bounded?

Comment: You have $X_1 \subset X_2 \subset X_3 \subset \dotsc$ and $X = \bigcup X_n$. What do you know about $\mu(X_n)$?

Comment: $\mu(X_n) = 0$, so then because of the subadditivity of $\mu$, it follows that $\mu(X) = 0$. But because $f$ is non constant a.e. there exists $c_1$ so that $\mu(A) > 0$ with $A = \{x \in X : f(x) < c_1\}$, but $A ⊂ X$, so that can't happen if $B = \mathbb{R}$, so $B$ must be bounded from above?

Comment: We don't know that $\mu(X_n) = 0$. In general, it won't be. But $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \mu(X_n) = \mu(X)$.

Comment: So if $c_0 = \infty$, then $\mu(X) = 0$ And then because of what I said from the second sentence, we see that $c_0$ can't be $\infty$? Is my notion about the existence of $c_1$ correct? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, we have $c_0 = \sup B = +\infty \iff \mu(X) = 0$. If $\mu(X) > 0$, because $\mu(X_n) \to \mu(X)$, we must have $\mu(X_n) > 0$ for some $n$. With $X_n = \{x : f(x) \leqslant n\}$, monotonicity yields $\mu^\ast(\{ x : f(x) \leqslant c\}) > 0$ for all $c \geqslant n$, whence $c_0 \leqslant n$.

Answer (score 1):

Solution from comments by  [Daniel Fischer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/705660/question-about-supremum-involving-non-constant-function-a-e#comment1477586_705660).

Let $X_n=  \{ x : f(x) \leqslant n\}$. You have $X_1 \subset X_2 \subset X_3 \subset \dotsc$ and $X = \bigcup X_n$.  Therefore,  $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \mu(X_n) = \mu(X)$.

It follows that  $c_0 = \sup B = +\infty \iff \mu(X) = 0$. If $\mu(X) > 0$, because $\mu(X_n) \to \mu(X)$, we must have $\mu(X_n) > 0$ for some $n$. With $X_n = \{x : f(x) \leqslant n\}$, monotonicity yields $\mu^\ast(\{ x : f(x) \leqslant c\}) > 0$ for all $c \geqslant n$, whence $c_0 \leqslant n$.

---

By the way, the assumption that every level set $\{f=c\}$ has measure zero was not used; it is not needed here.